# Computer Restarts while on UPS

Tags: power-supply, power, shutdown, desktop-computer, ups

I am using a 650va ups (not a good brand) My previous pc had 400w psu and it worked fine.
Now i am using a new pc (i5 10400f, gtx 1660ti oc, 550w 80bronze psu)

Whenever the electricity goes off, trip switch inside the ups starts switching repeatedly...when i click on shutdown or sleep, pc turns off immediately (not a clean shutdown) and restarts. This continues until i turn off the ups.

Does anybody know the reason behind this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A 650va UPS will likely have a wattage rating less then the PSU (VA is less then watts).  Your UPS switching tome may also be to slow for the psu to handle.

Comment: The relation between VA and Watts is the square-root of 2 or (roughly) 1.41. Worst case the PSU will draw (100/efficenty rating)* Watts * 1.41 VA. The UPS should be able to deliver slightly more than that to be on the safe side. In your case (100/80)*550*1.4 = 970 VA. Even if your PC doesn't really need the full capacity of the PSU 650VA is just too tight. 650VA can only supply upto 2/3 of the maximum load on the PSU. Your old PC had a 700 VA worst case draw and probably only used 80% or so, so 650 VA was enough.

Comment: Understood..Thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently the UPS is insufficient for your new setup.

650VA usually means 400 Watts, while you need 550 Watts.

I also remark that any given UPS will degrade with time, so that yours
might not be able today to do as well as it did in the past.